# how to open a new window with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing automation on a website.

I do a search on this site and your result returns a link for me to access, click it to open a new tab, but I want to open a new window

this is my code to click the link

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabelaResultado"]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/span/a'))).click()
```

I tried using the SHIFT keyboard shortcut

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabelaResultado"]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/span/a'))).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT).click()
```

but I have a result error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Is there a way I can configure chrome so every time I click a link it opens a new window?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to write it like this by sending **Shift** and **Enter**:

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabelaResultado"]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/span/a'))).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

`send_keys()` as no return value, so you are getting `None`. You can do it with `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

link = WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout=60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tabelaResultado"]/div[1]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/span/a')))
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT, link).click().key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```